# Multiply strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multiplication

**Problem Set**- Given two non-negative integers num1 and num2 represented as strings, return the product of num1 and num2, also represented as a string.

My algorithm seems to work fine for all but one test case of palindrome from 1-9

**UPDATE**

Javascript has a parse method but I don't want to use that as the problem is from leetcode or a matter of fact from any such site and the problem sets says that explicitly.

```js
//**Input:**
var n1 = "123456789"
var n2 = "987654321"

var multiply = function(str1, str2) {
  var sum = 0, k = 1;
  for( var i = str1.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
      var val1 = parseInt(str1[i], 10) * k;

      k *= 10;
      var d = 1;
      for(var j = str2.length - 1; j >=0; j--){
          var val2 = parseInt(str2[j], 10) * d;
          d *= 10;

          sum +=  val1 * val2;

      }
  }
  return sum.toString();
};

console.log(multiply(n1,n2))
```

I cannot understand what's going wrong. Other palindromes work fine though.

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: I have updated a detailed problem statement than only the subject line stating the problem

Comment: If you are trying to multiply two strings, then your code meets integer overflow issue. You shouldn't compute the result product in an integer, just use a string as a container to hold your final product.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have given the input test case for which it fails i.e. palindrome multiplication

Comment: The problem is that `sum`(numeric) isn't large enough to hold the final value.  There is really no difference between this approach and `return str1 * str2;`

Comment: Why aren't you just parsing both numbers, then multiplying? What's the purpose of iterating the digits? Also, have you considered integer overflow?

Comment: NB: once the product needs more than 15-16 digits, it will not be precise anymore.

Comment: @cricket_007 Haha. I know Javascript has that. But I don't want to use that. Seriously I mean, two close votes, Does anyone has patience to read it through? What's wrong with the question. I am learning DS therefore opting. It would be much great if help can be provided regarding finding bug

Comment: I think you have all the elements in the comments: how many digits do you think the final result should have?

Comment: @hiimdaosui Ok. Good input. Will see a workaround that.

Comment: My suggestion would be to log the sum after every number. Watch the results change. Then do your own algorithm by hand and see where your result deviates

Comment: @cricket_007 I think I am finding a logical explanation regarding same. This algorithm is my own

Comment: I did all of those consoles but I am stuck with it since more than an hour or so

Comment: What is meant was, open a calculator or spreadsheet and write out the value you're expecting at every step

Comment: Have a look at how other arbitrary-precision libraries do multiplication.  [example big.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js/blob/master/big.js) find `P.times`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose of such an exercise is probably that you implement your own multiplication algorithm for big numbers. When an integer (the product in this case) needs more than 15-16 digits, JavaScript number type cannot store that with enough precision, and so the outcome will be wrong if you just use the multiplication operator on the inputs.

Even if you sum up smaller products in a number variable, that sum will eventually cross the limit of [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). You need to store the result of smaller calculations in another data structure, like an array or a string.

Here is a simple implementation of the [long multiplication algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication):

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
    const product = Array(a.length+b.length).fill(0);
    for (let i = a.length; i--; null) {
        let carry = 0;
        for (let j = b.length; j--; null) {
            product[1+i+j] += carry + a[i]*b[j];
            carry = Math.floor(product[1+i+j] / 10);
            product[1+i+j] = product[1+i+j] % 10;
        }
        product[i] += carry;
    }
    return product.join("").replace(/^0*(\d)/, "$1");
}

console.log(multiply("123456789", "987654321"));
```

Since ECMAScript 2020, JavaScript has the bigint data type, with which you can do such multiplications out of the box (note the `n` suffix):

```js
console.log((123456789n * 987654321n).toString());
```

NB: In a browser you don't need to call `toString()` explicitly, but the above Stack Snippet console implementation is limited, so it needs it.

Comment: Damn, I started with these modulo operations but gave up too early. Yes you are right and was reading about precision range only. I will be much careful moving forward. Now I know moment!

Comment: By the way, is this line different ```for (let j = b.length; j--; null) {```  from normal ```for loop``` declaration ?

Comment: That is similar to `for (let j = b.length-1; j>=0; j--)`; but the subtraction takes place where the condition should be, which makes the third part of the `for` loop obsolete. To highlight this, I put a  `null` there. But choose what you are more comfortable with.

Comment: It relies on the fact that the postfix `--` first delivers the original value and only then decrements it. So the value is tested before it decrements, which means the loop will also execute (for the last time) with a `j` value that has become 0 (after the decrement).

Comment: Just a kind of review. This solution returned "0000.." for array of all zeros . So I kind of checked sum for array ```const sumArr = product.reduce( (acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
    if(sumArr === 0) {
        return "0";
    }```

Can it be done better ?

Comment: You can make the regex at the end a bit more eager to eat zeroes. I had assumed the input would already be canonical. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

With Chrome you have access to `BigInt` arithmetic with arbitrarily (usual disclaimers apply) large integers. Run the example to see that it *does* make a difference.

```js
let p1 = BigInt(1000000000) * BigInt(123456789) + BigInt(123456789)
  , p2 = BigInt(1000000000) * BigInt(987654321) + BigInt(987654321)
  ;
  
console.log(`standard: =${123456789 * 987654321}`);
console.log(`standard large: =${123456789123456789 * 987654321987654321}`);
console.log(`BigInt: =${p1 * p2}`);
```

Comment: Thanks man. I almost bammed my head! Was about to accept the solution until the one from @trincot came up. +1d

Comment: @kushalvm You're welcome. And it's a good approach to favor the answers of significantly more experienced SO users ... ;)

Comment: You both pointed out the bug but he gave the solution as well ;) You guys are almost gurus to me with that score. Hardly makes a difference to me comparing you both.

Comment: And for the experienced user concept if it's in your mind, then you most probably be doing the same. Haha!