# JavaScript do wrong multiplication when the numbers are too larger || return round off of multiplication result

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I am try to solve a problem of LEETCODE using JavaScript, the problem is *Multiply Strings* and the solution is:

```
const string = (num) => {
     return '' + num
 }
 
var multiply = function(num1, num2) {
    let result =  string(num1*num2)
    return result
    
};

console.log(multiply("123456789",
"987654321"))
```

it should return  *"121932631112635269"*

but it returns *121932631112635260*

Any Solution?

"123456789" * "987654321" should return *"121932631112635269"*

but it returns *121932631112635260*

Comment: That number is [two orders of magnitude larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: Also related: [Multiply strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51424468)

Comment: Check https://leetcode.com/problems/multiply-strings/solution/